# Open popup on marker hover

Tags: openlayers-6

I need to implement a function that can open a popup with some information by hover on a marker placed in the map.
I'm using openlayers 6 I tried to follow the example in the openlayers documentation but it doesn't work.
This is how I create a point:

```
var lonLat = ol.proj.fromLonLat([Lon, Lat])
  var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: [
        new ol.Feature({
          geometry: new ol.geom.Point(lonLat)
        })
      ]
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 46],
        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        src: pinPath,
        scale: 1
      })
    })
  });
  layer.set("layerId", "Point");
  if (this.map) {
    this.map.addLayer(layer);
    this.map.getView().animate({ zoom: Zoom, center: lonLat });

  }
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any relevant code, how you try to achieve this at the moment?

EDIT:

Here is a working proof of concept (btw. this is how you can turn your layer on and off).

https://jsfiddle.net/ckxmueqb/7/

Complete example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
        .map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        html, body {height:100%}

    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
<button onClick=switchLayer();>switch Layer</button>
<div id="map" class="map">
</div>

<div id="popup">
  <span>Hello there</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

let map;
let vectorSource;
let vectorLayer;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    drawMap();
});

function drawMap() {

    const container = document.getElementById('popup');
    const popupOverlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: {
            animation: {
                duration: 250,
            },
        },
    });

    const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([809549.1064227211, 6908390.40501351]),
    });


    const osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM({}),
    });

    vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [
            iconFeature,
        ],
    });

    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource,
    });

    map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            osm,
            vectorLayer,
        ],
        view: new ol.View(),
    });

    map.addOverlay(popupOverlay);

    map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
        const pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
        const hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
        if (hit) {
            //How to get all features you hover on.
            //const featureArray = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(pixel);

            popupOverlay.element.hidden = false;
            popupOverlay.setPosition(e.coordinate);
        } else {
            popupOverlay.element.hidden = true;
        }
    });

    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent(), map.getSize());
}

function switchLayer() {
    vectorLayer.setVisible(!vectorLayer.getVisible());
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I done following this example: https://jsbin.com/nebidok/1/edit?html,js,output

This is how I do it now:

```
 this.popupOverlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: document.getElementById('popup'),
  });
  this.map.addOverlay(this.popupOverlay);
```

I create the overlay object attached to a DIV with id=popup and then I attach it to the map.

```
this.map.on("pointermove", function (evt) {
    const element = this.popupOverlay.getElement();
    var Coord = ol.proj.transform([evt.coordinate[0], evt.coordinate[1]], 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:4326');
    $(element).popover('dispose');
    this.popupOverlay.setPosition(Coord);
    $(element).popover({
      container: element,
      placement: 'top',
      animation: false,
      html: true,
      title:"PopUp",
      content: '<p>The location you clicked was:</p><code>' + Coord[0] + '</code>'
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  }.bind(this));
```

Then when the event is fired I do this. Using the developer tools I can see that the DIV is correctly created an inside that there are the informations I write in code like title and content, but its not displayed in the map.

Comment: Are you sure your view has EPSG 4326? OpenLayers has EPSG 3857 as default projection. And why are you transforming event coordinates from 900913 to 4326, this makes no sense. Btw. you can pass evt.coordinates directly to transform function: ol.proj.transform(evtl.coordinate, '', '');

Comment: Yes, I'm sure my map is created using EPSG4326. I understand your comment, but the code I posted works, so I don't want to change nothing! ;)

Comment: Ok, but your event coordinates can't be in EPSG 900913, so you don't have to transform anything.